# Take information from preexisting database list and display it "on the fly" in styled text

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a question that I am having a hard time articulating so if my title needs to be changed please let me know. ;)
I am working on a classifieds website. Users are asked to select the city they want to see ads that are within that city. Those cites are listed under their parent countries like so

CANADA - 155 posts
-Toronto
-Halifax
-ect...
USA - 78 posts
-Detroit
-Chicago
-ect...
So thats great, the list populates correctly and everything works as far as that is concerned.
The problem I am having is that I would like to isolate the countries from the list with their post counts on the fly to use elsewhere in the site. I cant figure out how to separate that information from the list itself. I understand that this code: 
 `<div><a href="<?php echo $country_url; ?>" class="citylist_country"><?php echo $country['countryname']; ?> <?php if($show_region_adcount) echo "(".(0+$country_adcounts[$country['countryid']]).")"; ?></a></div>`
is what pulls that information in that I want into the list but I just want a page on my site to have basic text saying something to the effect of
"Currently Canada has 155 posts and USA has 78"
**I guess what I am asking is how do I pull in a single country name and its post counts individually without calling in the whole list? I am aware that this should be simple, but I am self taught everything so please excuse me if this seems silly.**
I have included all of the code below as I know this is helpful

```
<?php

require_once("initvars.inc.php");
require_once("config.inc.php");

?>
<table width="100%"><tr><td valign="top">
<?php

// Show city list

if($location_sort) 
{
    $sort1 = "ORDER BY countryname";
    $sort2 = "ORDER BY cityname";
}
else
{
    $sort1 = "ORDER BY c.pos";
    $sort2 = "ORDER BY ct.pos";
}

if ($show_region_adcount || $show_city_adcount)
{
    // First get ads per city and country
    $country_adcounts = array();
    $city_adcounts = array();
    $sql = "SELECT ct.cityid, c.countryid, COUNT(*) as adcnt
            FROM $t_ads a
                INNER JOIN $t_cities ct ON ct.cityid = a.cityid AND ($visibility_condn)
                INNER JOIN $t_countries c ON ct.countryid = c.countryid
            WHERE ct.enabled = '1' AND c.enabled = '1'
            GROUP BY ct.cityid";

    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error().$sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $country_adcounts[$row['countryid']] += $row['adcnt'];
        $city_adcounts[$row['cityid']] += $row['adcnt'];
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $t_countries c INNER JOIN $t_cities ct ON c.countryid = ct.countryid AND ct.enabled = '1' WHERE c.enabled = '1' GROUP BY c.countryid $sort1";
$resc = mysql_query($sql);

$country_count = mysql_num_rows($resc);
//$split_at = ($country_count%3?((int)($country_count/3))+2:($country_count/3)+1);
$percol = floor($country_count/$location_cols);
$percolA = array();
for($i=1;$i<=$location_cols;$i++) $percolA[$i]=$percol+($i<=$country_count%$location_cols?1:0);

$i = 0; $j = 0;
$col = 1;
while($country = mysql_fetch_array($resc))
{
    /* Begin Version 5.0 */
    $country_url = buildURL("main", array((0-$country['countryid']), $country['countryname']));
    /* End Version 5.0 */
?>


    <div><a href="<?php echo $country_url; ?>" class="citylist_country"><?php echo $country['countryname']; ?> <?php if($show_region_adcount) echo "(".(0+$country_adcounts[$country['countryid']]).")"; ?></a></div>


    <?php

    if($country['countryid'] == $xcountryid || !$expand_current_region_only)
    {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $t_cities ct WHERE countryid = $country[countryid] AND enabled = '1' $sort2";
        $resct = mysql_query($sql);

        /* Begin Version 5.0 */
        $citycount = mysql_num_rows($resct);
        /* End Version 5.0 */

        while($city=mysql_fetch_array($resct))
        {        
            /* Begin Version 5.0 */
            if ($shortcut_regions && $citycount == 1 
                    && $city['cityname'] == $country['countryname']) {
                continue;
            }

            $city_url = buildURL("main", array($city['cityid'], $city['cityname']));
            /* End Version 5.0 */

    ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $city_url; ?>" class="citylist_city"><?php echo $city['cityname']; ?> <?php if($show_city_adcount) echo "(".(0+$city_adcounts[$city['cityid']]).")"; ?></a><br>

    <?php

        }
    }

    ?>


    <?php

    $i++; $j++;
    //if($i%$split_at == 0) echo "</td><td valign=\"top\">";
    if ($j%$percolA[$col]==0 && $i<$country_count) { echo "</td><td valign=\"top\">"; $col++; $j=0; } 

}

?>

</td></tr></table>
```

I really appreciate the help you guys give and its my birthday today, so maybe someone can throw this old dog a bone! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is - with an efficient or well written SQL query, you can get the data you want directly, without iterating through all data. Takes time to go through your code and understand the structure. Will see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this query is of help.

```
SELECT c.name, c.countryid, COUNT(a.id) 
    FROM country AS c, city AS ct, ads AS a
    WHERE c.enabled = '1' AND ct.countryid = c.countryid
    AND ct.enabled = '1' AND a.cityid = ct.cityid
GROUP BY c.countryid;
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery after all you dom load

```
 $("a.citylist_country").each(function () {
         //use this country name
         alert( $(this).html());
 });
```